# If body has this class, then place this content in #mydiv, else place other content in #mydiv

Tags: jquery, class

JS beginner here.

I need help with a script to place different content in a div depending on whether the page body tag has a class of "home" or not.

I am trying to use .hasClass & .html to achieve this. It seems like it should be extremely straightforward, but I can't figure it out. Lack of proper syntax knowledge? Incorrect declarations? I don't know, and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction!

```
    if ($("body").hasClass("home") == true) {
            ("#mobilemenu").html("<a href="#">HOME</a>");
    }
    else {
            ("#mobilemenu").html("<a href="#">NOT HOME</a>");
    }
```

the JSFiddle (which currently does nothing) is here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/aqyN4/

Links to other JSFiddles or questions with similar functions extremely welcome!

Thank you,

Ali

Comment: Did you take a look at the error console?

Comment: Fixed - http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/aqyN4/5/

Comment: Yes, I use the error console. I have all the bad habits of someone who mostly uses found scripts and modifies them syntax-intact, so my syntax when I'm forced to write one myself is appalling & usually wrong. I am learning, though.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you forgot `$` before `("#mobilemenu")` :

```
if ($("body").hasClass("home")) {
    $("#mobilemenu").html("<a href='#'>Alle Kategorien- HOME</a>");
}
else {
    $("#mobilemenu").html("<a href='#'>NOT HOME</a>");
}​
```

**demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/aqyN4/4/

Comment: also you had double-quote issues, which were resolved but not noted in the above.

Answer (score 3):

hasClass already tests for a true value, you don't need to make a comparison.

Also, the `("#mobilemenu")` tags did not have jQuery's `$` appended. This makes it an undeclared function. Also...you cannot open a statement with `"` and use it to encase strings unless you escape it, or use apostrophes. See working code below.

```
if ($("body").hasClass("home")) {
  $("#mobilemenu").html("<a href='#'>HOME</a>");
}
else{
  $("#mobilemenu").html("<a href='#'>NOT HOME</a>");
}
```