# How to mark current navbar-element as active in bootstrap and don`t lost it when screen will be updated?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I have navbar, that leads to different pages in my web application.

```html
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top navbar-ligth bg-fadded">
        <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light" th:href="@{/}">
            <img class="home-logo" alt="UTL-2" th:src="@{/static/img/site-logo.png}"/></a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul id="myDIV" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light" th:href="@{/login}">Login
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light" th:href="@{/plan}">Plan</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light" th:href="@{/orders}">Orders</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light" th:href="@{/stations}">Stations</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light" th:href="@{/partner}">Partners</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light" th:href="@{/map}">Map</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light" th:href="@{/info}">Info</a>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>
    </nav>
```

And I use such simple script to add "active" class to nav-item:

```html
    <script>
        var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myDIV");
        var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("nav-item");

        for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
            btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
                if (current.length > 0) {
                    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
                }
                this.className += " active";
            });
        }
    </script>
```

It works good and element marks as active in static test page, but when I click to link page is switched to another page and element is still don't have "active" class. Is there any way to update only body of webpage? Or mark element with "active" class some other way? How is it works in bootstrap?

I fount some solution using thymeleaf, question is how to get current active link:
th:classappend="${module == 'login' ? 'active' : ''}"
"module" is not correct element, what elevent can return current link?

Comment: Can't you simply add the `active` class to `.nav-bar` in your HTML on the pages that need it ? Or do you need it to change depending of the source of the navigation ?

Comment: I know how to add active class, question is how to add active class depending of the current page: home, login, etc.

Comment: You could add it using a simple if else statement ? Something along these lines : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364841/if-body-has-this-class-then-place-this-content-in-mydiv-else-place-other-cont ?

Comment: I found some solution with thymeleaf th:classappend="${module == 'login' ? 'active' : ''}" , but it seams "module" is not correct element, how to get current active link?

Comment: Since you haven't provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can't really help you out further

Answer (score 0):

After an hours that I spent to find some simple solution I wrote this script:

```html
<script>
        var currentPage = window.location.pathname;
        var items = document.getElementById("myDIV").getElementsByClassName("nav-item");
        var activeClass = "active";

        var patt = new RegExp(currentPage.split("/")[1],"i");

        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
            var navItem = items[i];
            var linkArray = navItem.children[0].href.split("/");
            var linkHTML = linkArray[linkArray.length - 1];
            if(patt.test(linkHTML)){
                navItem.classList.add("active");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

It works but this is impossible that in thymeleaf or bootstrap is no simple build-in solution of this task.